# password_verify() doesnt seem to work with database

Tags: php, mysql

This is my login verify. Im echoing everything for debugging

```
<?php
    echo $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $password = $_POST['password'];
    include 'conn.php';

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM user_info WHERE email=?");
    $sql->bind_param('s',$email);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $sql->close();
    echo $hash = $row['password'];
    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        echo 'Password is valid!';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid password.';
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

My SignUp page

```
<?php
          include 'conn.php';
          $name = $_POST['first_name']." ".$_POST['last_name'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];
          $gender = $_POST['gender'];

          $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_info` (`email`, `name`, `password`, `gender`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
          $sql->bind_param('sssi', $email, $name, $password, $gender);
          $sql->execute();
          $sql->close();
          $conn->close();
?>
```

[Snapshot of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSOoM.png)

Every time it just outputs to password invalid.

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($password);` after the `password_hash()` call and a `var_dump($password, $hash);` call before the `password_verify()` call? Please [edit] your question to include the generated output (and the changed source code).

Comment: add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to conn.php before mysqli_connect()

Comment: [Progman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286934/progman) Thankyou ! I tried  `var_dump($password, $hash);` and realised it took my `$password` variable from conn.php since I included it after `$password = $_POST['password']` and hence it always tried to validate my database password. I just changed my variable names now. Everything works. Thankyou